# Working with tensorflow's shuffle_batch method

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm experimenting with [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) and I'm trying to read from a `csv` file and print out a batch of its data via `shuffle_batch`. I've gone throw the [decode_csv docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#decode_csv) and the [shuffle_batch docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#shuffle_batch), but I'm still unable to get it working.

Here's what I have:
import tensorflow as tf

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
    ["./data/train.csv"], num_epochs=1, shuffle=True) # total record count in csv is 30K
reader = tf.TextLineReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

record_defaults = [["1"], ["2"]] # irrelevant for this discussion
input, outcome = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)

min_after_dequeue = 1000
batch_size = 10
capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size

example_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([outcome], batch_size, capacity, min_after_dequeue)
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess, coord=coord)
example_batch.eval(session = sess)
```

Running this will generate this exception:

```
OutOfRangeError: RandomShuffleQueue
    '_3_shuffle_batch_1/random_shuffle_queue' is closed 
    and has insufficient elements (requested 10, current size 0)
```

I'm not sure what the issue is. I have a feeling it's due to the session and the way I'm handling it; I'm probably not doing it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `num_epochs=1` from your `string_input_producer` initializer.

Comment: yep, that worked. Thanks a lot! ... can you tell me the reasoning behind it?

Comment: That param restricts the queue to only going through the data once, so I think it was running out of examples to fill up the queue. Perhaps the data doesn't have as many rows as you thought (off by one or something?)

Answer (score -2):

"Note: if num_epochs is not None, this function creates local counter epochs. Use local_variables_initializer() to initialize local variables." see from: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/string_input_producer